# How to have display information about a variable column in a gallery via radio button?

Tags: powerapps

I have a table like the one shown below

[image: screenshot]

I want to have a radio who choses the toy car and a galery that only show the information about said car.

Ive tried the property **thisitem.(variable)** but that does not work.

does anyone know any workaround?

PS:I've tried a bunch of *if* functions, but I have 200 itens and *if* functions in power apps only alow 50 itens.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Gallery.Items something like 
        Filter(Cars,cartype=radiobutton.value) 
where Cars is the table having all the details of the cars and radiobutton.value is the value selected.